# Spring configure MongoDB to create a MongoClient at runtime with dynamic database name

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm new in the world of spring and I want to implement the following with spring and mongodb:

I developed an architecture with multiple microservice connected via rest. Now I want to setup my datamanagementservice with mongodb. It is necessary to save userdata strictly seperated so I thought about using the user id which is a uuid string as database name. I also don't want to use JPA because I have custom and variable documents that don't match a predefined model. 
I found a few solutions that work when I testet them e.g. [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-db-factory-java) The problem is that when I extend `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` I have to override the method `getDatabaseName()` and ad far as I've seen in all the solutions the name is returned by calling a variable from the application properties.

**Problem:**

In my case the databasename is unknown before a client calls my microservice where the userid and so the databasename is passed to the service.

**QUESTIONS:**
Is it a possible solution to use the userid as databaename to create a "namespace" for the userdata?
Is it possible to use kind of a factory where I can pass in the authentication params , databasename and so on to get a Mongoclient/ Mongotemplate back?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you say "It is necessary to save user data strictly separated", have you considered the possibility of each user been represented by a distinct *gson document* in the same *collection*? Maybe this suits with your needs, and despite each of them might have distinct properties, probably they share a lot between them to be all considered as a part of the same collection. I suppose you already know it, but just in case, Mongo is a document-based NoSQL technology, and organizing your users in documents instead of different databases might help you to achieve a less complex data structure and with the possibility of using the distinct filters you can set up for fetching/inserting/updating/deleting documents in a collection. If you have not already done it, I would consider this possibility first, one collection and one single database, instead of multiple databases, one for each user. :)

This approach could also solve the getDatabaseName problem you have, since it could be known in advance by all. The "namespace" you mention could perfectly be your Mongo collection. By having a single database, you would not need a factory for getting your multiple database connections, what I consider it would not be as easy and cheap (in computational terms) to maintain (in a hypothetical context of multiple requests in a short period of time) as having a single connection, a lot less expensive than opening multiple ones in a very small time window. When your service receives the userId, you could perfectly filter the document corresponding to that user in the collection with a Mongo query.

Hope this suggestion helps you, I believe it could reduce considerably the complexity of the solution you might need, otherwise, could you please clarify with more details what do you mean by "save user data strictly separated"? If it is geographically, you could also use Mongo clusters, for example..

Comment: this is the old solution I already implemented which works. By seperating the data I mean that I have to handle health data which has to be treated very carefully. Thing I the data I upload is nested a few times because there are multiple devices, datacategories and features. So I was thinking about speeding the search part by reducing the entiries with using the userid as database name, the device name and datacategory as collection name und in this collection I store the feature data of the category.

Comment: Thank you, now I believe I understand it better. You put the focus on the eficiency and response times right? In my opinion (at least in the way I imagine it and from my experience) I strongly believe that it would take more time to establish a new database connection for each user you need to fetch from a device, than holding the same connection and make use of the Mongo indexes to speed up the queries. I agree that the nesting of the different data for distinct devices is not elegant, but Mongo is thought and optimized for those situations.

Comment: On the other hand, sometimes you might require to apply operations to a set of users (like adding a new attribute, modify a value). Those operations might become a lot more complex and time-expensive to handle if they are located  in distinct databases. I don't believe medical apps follow that approach, I believe they have it centralized in one or very few databases and with indexes. And another addition to that, it is not less important than the database: a good cache system on the client apps to not have to query the data so often if it is not expected to change continuously in time.

Comment: Yes and in addition to your point of view ( which totally makes sense to me, thank you) I guess scaling/clustering of the database might also be a lot easier I you have only one database and one documentstore. Only thing is that I'm not shure about e.g. Hipaa compliance. I know that the storing/handling of medical data is very restricted so maybe from that point of view there are some guidelines to follow.